# Restart or no Restart after config file change

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm

I have to make a small change to a SQL server config file (http://www.msbicoe.com/post/2013/05/06/SSRS-2012-Report-Server-cannot-load-the-TERADATASQLPDW-Extension-Error.aspx).

Do I need to restart the server in order for the changes to be made or will it be fine without?

Determines if I have to wait till an appropriate time to take the server down or just continue on after as normal.

Comment: It would not be _required_, but I would seriously consider finding a time when you can safely take down the server if you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let me point out that the change is not related to the configuration of SQL server but is a change in Reporting Services configuration: both are installed by the same package and are tightly coupled but are different products that do not share the configuration files.
To make changes in file 'rsreportserver.config' become effective a restart is not required.
I just made a test on my local SQL 2012 instance disabling some of the export formats and the change was immediately visible reloading a report; I loaded a report, checked that all the export formats were available, edited and saved the above mentioned config file commenting out pdf export format and finally reloaded the report: the export format i commented out was not available anymore even if I made no (explicit) restart.
since the config file you refer to is the same (I found the entry mentioned in the article) I expect these changes also to be immediately effective.